# Graph theory question on complete subgraphs at least half the size of the parent graph

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math

While studying olympiad mathematics I was stumped by this question. I paraphrase the question here:

> In a graph with $4k-1$ vertices, given that there is a least one complete subgraph with $2k$ vertices, but there are no complete subgraphs with $2k+1$ vertices. Show that every complete subgraph with $2k$ vertices contains the same common vertex.

While thinking about this problem:

- What would the converse of the statement be
- How to try construct a small counterexample and arrive at a contradiction
- What other proof techniques are useful, e.g. edge coloring

Comment: Take three complete subgraphs on $2k $ vertices that do not share a vertex and show you can build a complete subgraph of size $2k+1$

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.02877, Lemma 3.3